# How to use cbind to transfer 2 rows from one df into another in a 300+ column dataset

Tags: r, dplyr, cbind

I have 2 datasets, one has numerical variables and one has character variables, from `df1`.

In the character `df` I want to add `Respondent.ID` from `df1`.
In the numerical `df`, I want to add Column `ColumnName1` and `ColumnName2` from `df1`.

My `cbind()` is not working - when I run the code, it basically gives me the original dataframe, `df1`:

```
numericaldata <- dplyr::select_if(binarydata, is.numeric)
characterdata <- dplyr::select_if(binarydata, is.character)

characterdata <- cbind(binarydata,share = "Respondent.ID"])
numericaldata <- cbind(binarydata, share = "SectorCollapsed", "location")
```

Any help appreciated, thank you kindly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `cbind()` call is off. What it will do now is bind the columns of `binarydata` and one column called `share` with the same amount of rows as `binarydata` and with value `"Respondent.ID"` in every row.

Furthermore, when using `cbind()` you should pass along all the dataframes or columns that you would like to combine. A solution would be

```
characterdata <- cbind(characterdata, binarydata["Respondent.ID"])
numericaldata <- cbind(numericaldata, binarydata[, c("SectorCollapsed, location")])
```